# SSAS Cube Design for Rolling Up Line Items

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, cube, olap-cube

I've built a cube based on a fact table that contains a row for each item of a holiday / short break order.  Each part can be categorised as transport, hotel or event, so you might get any combination of 1-3 rows for each holiday booking.

I've created separate dimensions for hotel, transport and event with foreign keys in the fact table for each of these.

The overall booking ID is included as a degenerate dimension.

This leaves me with a slight problem in that I'd like to be able to look at the count / value of bookings where (for example) a hotel and transport were booked on the same booking order.

What would be the best way to handle this so it's easy to manipulate in an SSAS cube?  Any pointers would be welcome...

Comment: Hi Mat, not sure if I understood your problem. But does a CountDistinct solve your problem? (for multidim) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/distinctcount-mdx (for tabular) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492142.aspx